# Launch GUI program at host through SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

I've got a Raspberry Pi connected to my TV, with no mouse or keyboard.

I'm `ssh`ing into it, starting X and then I want to launch VLC (or any other GUI program, for that matter). If I `ssh -X`, that will open the program in the computer I'm `ssh`ing from, not on the TV.

How can I launch a program and make it appear on the TV?

Comment: `export DISPLAY=:0 ; vlc`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Can you please post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: [How to start a GUI software on a remote Linux PC via SSH](https://askubuntu.com/q/47642) and friends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `DISPLAY` environment variable needs to have a value set to which display the program should be opened. If you set it to `:0`, it means the first local screen.

This should in other words open vlc on the first local screen;

```
export DISPLAY=:0 ; vlc
```

Answer (score 14):

Slightly less typing than Joachim's (and actually slightly different behavior):

```
DISPLAY=:0 vlc
```

This doesn't actually set the DISPLAY variable to :0 for the whole shell session, only passes it to vlc.

So:

- If you want to start other X programs in that session after VLC, Joachim's is better.
- If you just want to run VLC ASAP, this is faster by 9 keypresses. :)

*(I wanted to add this only as a comment, but I didn't have enough points for that, sorry.)*